# PHP class using mysqli

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I need something like this.

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_password); 

 class webFile {

 function __construct($querystr){

 if ($result = $this->$mysqli->query($querystr)) { 

 while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ echo $row['name']; } 

 $result->close(); 

 }}}

 $object = new webFile($querystr);
```

I try in different variants, but somethink do not work.
I interested in `mysqli->query` not `mysqli_query(a,b);`

**UPD**
1. Your solutions not work.
2. Thanks, work fine, the problem was with DB also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `global` for PHP to look in the global scope and see your `$mysqli` variable, and because this is a global variable you can't use `$this`:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_password); 

class webFile {

function __construct($querystr){
global $mysqli;
if ($result = $mysqli->query($querystr)) { 

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ echo $row['name']; } 

$result->close(); 

}}}

$object = new webFile($querystr);
```

You could also just pass your `MySQLi` object to your constructor and have a property:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_password); 

class webFile {

function __construct($querystr, $conn){
$this->mysqli = $conn;
if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($querystr)) { 

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ echo $row['name']; } 

$result->close(); 

}}
private $mysqli;
}

$object = new webFile($querystr, $mysqli);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this perhaps, injecting the connection into the class constructor.

```
<?php
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $oConn=new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname);

    class webFile{
        private $conn;

        public function __construct( $conn=object, $sql=false, $field=false ){
            if( $conn && $sql && $field ){
                $this->conn=$conn;
                $res=$this->conn->query( $sql );
                if( $res ){
                    while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) echo $rs->$field;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    $obj=new webFile( $oConn, 'select * from users', 'user' );

?>
```